# Error when compiling apache, "Undefined symbols:Undefined symbols:"_apr_dir_read$INODE64"......ld: symbol(s) not found"

Tags: macos, module, apache2, compilation, building

I am trying to compile Apache. I did download the latest version of the sourcecode (2.2.17). This is what I do:

```
> sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --with-included-apr --enable-mods-shared=all --enable-module=so

> sudo make
```

and when doing that I get:

```
/Users/Niklas/Development/apache/httpd-2.2.17/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -g -O2        -o httpd  modules.lo buildmark.o -export-dynamic server/libmain.la modules/http/libmod_http.la modules/mappers/libmod_so.la server/mpm/prefork/libprefork.la os/unix/libos.la  /Users/Niklas/Development/apache/httpd-2.2.17/srclib/pcre/libpcre.la /Users/Niklas/Development/apache/httpd-2.2.17/srclib/apr-util/libaprutil-1.la -lexpat -liconv /Users/Niklas/Development/apache/httpd-2.2.17/srclib/apr/libapr-1.la -lpthread
Undefined symbols:
  "_apr_dir_read$INODE64", referenced from:
      _process_resource_config_nofnmatch in libmain.a(config.o)
      _ap_process_resource_config in libmain.a(config.o)
  "_apr_file_info_get$INODE64", referenced from:
      _ap_pcfg_openfile in libmain.a(util.o)
  "_apr_dir_open$INODE64", referenced from:
      _process_resource_config_nofnmatch in libmain.a(config.o)
      _ap_process_resource_config in libmain.a(config.o)
  "_apr_stat$INODE64", referenced from:
      _ap_process_resource_config in libmain.a(config.o)
      _ap_mpm_set_coredumpdir in libmain.a(mpm_common.o)
      _ap_is_directory in libmain.a(util.o)
      _ap_is_rdirectory in libmain.a(util.o)
      _ap_log_pid in libmain.a(log.o)
      _unixd_pre_config in libos.a(unixd.o)
      _resolve_symlink in libmain.a(request.o)
      _resolve_symlink in libmain.a(request.o)
      _resolve_symlink in libmain.a(request.o)
      _ap_directory_walk in libmain.a(request.o)
      _ap_directory_walk in libmain.a(request.o)
      _ap_directory_walk in libmain.a(request.o)
      _ap_sub_req_lookup_dirent in libmain.a(request.o)
      _ap_sub_req_lookup_dirent in libmain.a(request.o)
      _ap_sub_req_lookup_file in libmain.a(request.o)
      _ap_sub_req_lookup_file in libmain.a(request.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [httpd] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using OSX but I guess that shouldn't matter?

I have been struggling with this for several days so I hope someone can point me in the rigth direction?

Thank you in advnace!

Regards,
Niklas

Comment: I solved it. I did download the sourcecode again and did it all over again. I must have destroyed something when trying to fix the problem, but with a fresh install it is now compiling.

Comment: Re-downloading worked for me too -- wierd!!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to build on OSX? Do you have the dev tools installed?

Your compile definitely failed which is why it's not working. You would probably be better off looking for precompiled packages to do what you need to do. At the very least you would be better off looking for guides to building apache on OSX.

Apache also has a way to compile install just the modules you're trying to add on using a utility called `apxs2`. OSX should have Apache installed already and I can't imagine they wouldn't have enabled that in their build.

Granted I don't know for sure but a good place to start would be to Google `install mod_dbd on OSX`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Well, it's a bit strange but the "MySQL-driver" isn't compiled together together with Apache2. I believe I read something about licensing issues, not sure though. Hence, that's why it is complaining about DBRiver = mysql in httpd.config. I think mod_dbd is properly installed, it's the mysql-driver I don't get properly included, I have updated my question to reflect this. Don't know about apxs2, will check it out (but no instructions I found pointed to it...). How do I verify if the dev tools are installed? I am new to the most of the activities for getting this in place...

Comment: Ok, it seems like my problem starts way before when it is time to compile or use the mod_dbd module. I have updated my question in order to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem while building httpd 2.4.2 on Mac OS X, first download the latest APR from here http://apr.apache.org/ then compile and install it somewhere, then reconfigure httpd like this

```
./configure --with-apr=/Users/youruser/where/you/installed/apr
```